# How do I return only the required fields in NestJs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to get all the records from the table.

controller:

```
  @Get('types')
  async getTypes(): Promise<PageTypeRO[]> {
      return this.pageService.findTypes();
  };
```

service:

```
 async findTypes(): Promise<PageTypeRO[]> {
     return await this.pageTypePropsRepository.find();
 }
```

interface (RO):

```
export interface PageTypeRO {
    readonly id: number
}
```

I expect to get an array with objects in which only the "id" field, but teach all the fields from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set columns you want to get,
To make it work for you, you should edit FindTypes function:

```
async findTypes(): Promise<PageTypeRO[]> {
    return await this.pageTypePropsRepository.find({ select: ["id"] });
}
```